# How to use one entity in another entity two times in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an Airport entity which is like;

```
    @Table(name = "Airport")
public class Airport extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id", unique = true, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "Name", unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "IcaoCode", unique = true)
    private String icaoCode; //International Civil Aviation Organisation

    private String city;
}
```

and I have also Route entity which has departure and destination airports;

```
@Table(name = "Route")
public class Route extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id", unique = true, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "DeparturePlace")
    private Airport departurePlace;
    
    @Column(name = "DestinationPlace")
    private Airport destinationPlace;
}
```

What I would like to do is to create Routes with unique pair destination-departure places and destination and departure cannot be equal to eachother.

Edit:
One route must only consists of 2 airports which are departure and destination. Besides, if I have airports like A-B-C, I should be allowed to create different unique routes like below;

```
A->B
A->C
B->C
B->A
C->A
C->B
```

is there one-to-one relationship between Airport and Route ? If so, how should I annotate departurePlace and destinationPlace fields in Route ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is one-To-one relationship, so your Route entity will be like

```
@OneToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "DeparturePlace_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Airport departurePlace;

@OneToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "DestinationPlace_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Airport destinationPlace;
```

Like comment discussion one airport can be in many routes :

In Airport entity you need to add

```
@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name="route_id")
Route route();
```

Hope useful

Comment: While one-to-one relationships are a thing they are wrong here, since there can be certainly be multiple routes starting at one airport.

Comment: I don't have the spec to knwo if will be multiple or not, maybe one route by distination it's logic !!!

Comment: @JensSchauder that is what I want to do. Lets Assume that I have airports A-B-C and I want to define routes like {A-B},{A-C} {B-C} etc. how can I make such relationship ?

Comment: So in the example can't be a route {A-D}??? Or to make it concrete: If there is a flight from Los Angeles to New York there can't be a flight from Los Angeles to Frankfurt or anywhere else?

Comment: @JensSchauder if there is  flight from Los Angeles to New york, it should also be allowed to have flight from los angeles to Frankfurt.   

Airports: A-B-C-D-E-F
a couple of routes:  {A-C} {A-D} {A-F} {C-A} {A-E} etc.

Comment: If i understand you, relationships for this case is one-to-many (one airport) have many route ?! let me know if this waht you search for edit my answer

Comment: @Yekta Anıl Aksoy if my answer resolve your issue plz don't forget to accept it :)

Comment: @A.khalifa yes,  one airport can be in many routes as destination or departure place. However one route can only have departure and destination places.

Comment: @A.khalifa since we have 2 airport fields in Route entity, should we have  2 Route lists in Airport Entity or  one is enough as you mentioned ?